# Method that returns two classes in java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, methods

I have two classes:

```
public class UnoLoginPageUi {
    public final Input username = new Input("id=username");
    public final Input password = new Input("id=password");
    public final Button loginButton = new Button("name=login");
}
```

and

```
public class DuoLoginPageUi {
    public final Input username = new Input("id=usernameField");
    public final Input password = new Input("id=passwordField");
    public final Button loginButton = new Button("id=submitButton");
}
```

and in one common class I want to make something like that:

```
public void loginUsingUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password, String pageType) {
    getUi(pageType).username.waitForToBeDisplayed();
    getUi(pageType).username.setValue(username);
    getUi(pageType).password.setValue(password);
    getUi(pageType).loginButton.click();
}
```

where getUi() is a method that gas argument pageType (which is UNO or DUO).

```
private Class getUi(String pageType) {
    if (pageType.equals("UNO")) {
        return new DuoLoginPageUi();
    }
    else if (pageType.equals("DUO")) {
        return new UnoLoginPageUi;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However it doesn't work as this method need to in type of this two pages with selectors - how to deal with that ?

Comment: add more detail how method gonna call from these two classes. ur question contains only code

Comment: Create an interface that each of those classes implement. Use that interface as return type. Also, use an enum rather than a String for the page type.

Comment: What´s the error? `return new UnoLoginPageUi;` need () btw.  If you do it this way you need to check type every time. create a Wrapper for those UI-Classes and extend them from Wrapper. So u can use this type and simply null check and cast it when you need it.

Comment: Replace the return type, currently `Class` with `Object`

Comment: You can Use Interface On Your Code

Comment: I also hope you realise that every time you call `getUi(pageType)` it is returning a new instance. by the time you call `getUi(pageType).loginButton.click();` the instance returned has no values set.

Comment: Interface as suggested by @Xing is a perfect solution .To add to your question ,instead of using pageType.equals java provides  instanceof check which will help you to check whether pageType is an instanceof DUO or UNO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a common abstraction for the two classes

```
public abstract class LoginPageUi {
    public final Input username = new Input("id=username");
    public final Input password = new Input("id=password");
    public final Button loginButton = new Button("name=login");        
}
```

and have `UnoLoginPageUi` and `DuoLoginPageUi` extend that

```
public class UnoLoginPageUi extends LoginPageUi {
    public static String getPageType() { return "UNO"; }
}

public class DuoLoginPageUi extends LoginPageUi {
    public static String getPageType() { return "DUO"; }
}
```

The method would return the common abstraction

```
private LoginPageUi getUi(String pageType) {
    if (pageType.equals(DuoLoginPageUi.getPageType())) {
        return new DuoLoginPageUi();
    }
    else if (pageType.equals(UnoLoginPageUi.getPageType())) {
        return new UnoLoginPageUi;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I also hope you realize that every time you call `getUi(pageType)` it is returning a new instance. by the time you call `getUi(pageType).loginButton.click();` the instance returned has no values set.

Refactor:

```
public void loginUsingUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password, String pageType) {
    LoginPageUi ui = getUi(pageType);
    if (ui != null) {
        ui.username.waitForToBeDisplayed();
        ui.username.setValue(username);
        ui.password.setValue(password);
        ui.loginButton.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a interface called LoginPageUi. And let your UnoLoginPageUi and DuoLoginPageUi implement that interface.

Then your getUi method will be `private LoginPageUi getUi(String pageType)`.

Off topic: I would recommend to implement an enum instead of String pageType.

Comment: yup thats what i m going to answer :D

Answer (score 0):

create Parent class or interface for both called UI:

```
public abstract class Ui{
}

public interface Ui{
}
```

and extend it:

```
public class UnoLoginPageUi extends Ui{
  public final Input username = new Input("id=username");
  public final Input password = new Input("id=password");
  public final Button loginButton = new Button("name=login");
}

public class DuoLoginPageUi extends Ui {
  public final Input username = new Input("id=usernameField");
  public final Input password = new Input("id=passwordField");
  public final Button loginButton = new Button("id=submitButton");
}
```

or

```
public class UnoLoginPageUi implements Ui{
  public final Input username = new Input("id=username");
  public final Input password = new Input("id=password");
  public final Button loginButton = new Button("name=login");
}

public class DuoLoginPageUi implements Ui {
  public final Input username = new Input("id=usernameField");
  public final Input password = new Input("id=passwordField");
  public final Button loginButton = new Button("id=submitButton");
}
```

then return parent reference as:

```
private Ui getUi(String pageType) {
if (pageType.equals("UNO")) {
    return new DuoLoginPageUi();
}
else if (pageType.equals("DUO")) {
    return new UnoLoginPageUi;
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is ok, but you should make `Ui` an interface or an abstract class since it's not having any behaviour or fields.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't case like that:
getUi("DUO").password.setValue(password);

Comment: Since password field is **final**, you can't change it :)

Comment: You have to remove final modifier of fields.

Comment: It's not fault of modifiers,  actuall after I try cast some selector like above I can do only .getClass or call another function on getUi().  - but not selector.